# Show $3x_1x_2-2x_1^2-2x_2^2<0$ is negative

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

How do I show that: $$h=3x_1x_2-2x_1^2-2x_2^2<0 \\ \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$$

My attempt:
$$h=7x_1x_2-2(x_1+x_2)^2$$
But
$$ (x_1+x_2)^2 > 2x_1x_2 \\ \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$$
Therefore
$$h<3x_1x_2$$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Note $h = -2(x_1-x_2)^2-x_1x_2 = -2(x_1+x_2)^2+7x_1x_2$.  Choose the appropriate expression depending on the sign of $x_1x_2$ to make your case.

Comment: Or if you prefer, $h=-\frac14(x+y)^2-\frac74(x-y)^2$

Comment: So I have $h=-x_1x_2-2(x_1-x_2)^2$ for $x_1x_2<0$, $h<0$. Now for $x_1x_2>0$, $(x_1-x_2)^2 >=0$ therefore $(x_1-x_2)^2>-\frac{1}{2}x_1x_2$, therefore $h<0$. Is that correct?

Comment: If $x_1x_2>0$, use the first expression.  Else use the second.